# Keyboard layout Asus Eeepc 1015

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, keyboard-layout, eeepc

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to use Ubuntu (11.10) on my Netbook (Asus Eeepc 1015) trough USB boot, but my keyboard layout is all messed up.
It's like the "o" key is 6, the "k" is 2 and go on.
I've searched on the keyboard layout settings for a proper layout, but no luck.

Is it a prob from booting from USB or there is a drive download or something to fix that?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `NumLock` is turned on. You have two options:

1) You can turn it off using `Fn+Insert` (`NumLk`) once you're logged in

[image]

2) You can turn off numlock by default in the BIOS

Comment: I've tried that.. Didn't work.
So, I reflashed my pendrive (with the same Ubuntu) and all worked out normaly.
Thx for the answer anyway.